# How to map a multiple column unique contraint in hibernate with an abstract class field and a subclass field

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, hbmxml

In short: Is there a way to write a hibernate xml mapping with a two column unique constraint, where one field of the unique constraint is part of the mapping of an abstract class and another field is defined in the subclass mapping?

Long version: I have a class `AbstractCustomFieldValue` which references two other classes, some entity `RefType` and another entity `CustomField`. `AbstractCustomFieldValue` has several implementations as shown below.

```
public abstract class AbstractCustomFieldValue<RefType extends SomeInterface>
{
    protected long id;
    protected RefType refObjekt;
    protected CustomField customField;
    protected String value;
}

public class MyEntityCustomFieldValue extends AbstractCustomFieldValue<MyEntity>
{
}

public class MyOtherEntityCustomFieldValue extends AbstractCustomFieldValue<MyOtherEntity>
{
}
```

`AbstractCustomFieldValue` is mapped as an abstract class, the implementations are mapped as subclasses.

```
<class name="AbstractCustomFieldValue" abstract="true">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="MyUniqueIdGenerator"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="customField" class="CustomField" column="customfield_id"/>
    <property name="value" length="65535"/>
</class>

<union-subclass name="MyEntityCustomFieldValue" extends="AbstractCustomFieldValue" table="my_entity_customfield_values">
    <many-to-one name="refObjekt" class="MyEntity" column="ref_id"/>
</union-subclass>

<union-subclass name="MyOtherEntityCustomFieldValue" extends="AbstractCustomFieldValue" table="my_other_entity_customfield_values">
    <many-to-one name="refObjekt" class="MyOtherEntity" column="ref_id"/>
</union-subclass>
```

The combination of `refObjekt` and `customField` needs to be unique. Is there a way to achieve this with this mapping?

I still have the option to define a unique key in the database without hibernate or to remove `customField` from the abstract mapping and to place it into the subclass mapping:

```
<properties name="myUniqueKey" unique="true">
    <many-to-one name="customField" class="CustomField" column="customfield_id"/>
    <many-to-one name="refObjekt" class="MyEntity" column="ref_id"/>
</properties>
```

But is there a way to keep `customField` in the mapping of the abstract class and still to be able to define a hibernate unique constraint?

Answer (score 0):

You can define any custom DDL in hbm mappings using [<database-object>](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/mapping-database-object.html). You can create unique constraints there; hbm2ddl will execute it.

Comment: Depends how the abstract superclass is mapped. If the abstract class is mapped to a table with `@Entity` rather than being a `@MappedSuperclass` I believe it is not possible to create such a uniqueness constraint that is enforced by the database. In this case you probably have to enforce it programmatically within your Entity or an EntityListener but i think performance would be pretty poor.